# Password Checker in C

Tags: c

I wanted to build a simple program that checks whether the user entered a password with at least one uppercase letter, one number and one symbol. Then if true print "This is a strong password".
But, when I started testing it, if I enter a pass like SS2, It counts as an strong password...

```
int issymbol(int password) {
    if (password >= 33 && password <= 47) return 1;
    else if (password >= 58 && password <= 64) return 1;
    else if (password >= 91 && password <= 96) return 1;
    else if (password >= 123 && password <= 126) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char password[7];
    int i;
    int u, d, s;        // u - uppercase character
                        // d - digit
    u = d = s = 0;      // s - symbol

    scanf("%s", password);

    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if ( isupper(password[i]) && (u == 0) )
            u++;
        if ( isdigit(password[i]) && (d == 0) )
            d++;
        if ( issymbol(password[i]) && (s == 0) )   // Checks if password[i] is a symbol
            s++;
        if ( (u + d + s) >= 3) {
            printf("Your password is strong!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( (u + d + s) < 3)  printf("Your password is weak:(\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas for improving it is welcome.

Comment: Again a perfect opportunity to learn what a great tool a debugger is.

Comment: End loop condition is wrong, it must depend on password length.

Comment: `scanf("%s", password);` --> `scanf("%6s", password);`

Comment: When you enter `SS2` it hits a score of 3 and then breaks.  If you don't like that, then change your logic.

Comment: Yeah by using @Bathsheba logic it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you mean `if (u >= 1 && d >= 1 && s >= 1)` for a strong password? Then you can drop the tedium of writing `&& (u == 0)` etc.

Your current test is little more than a character count.

Also, your code is quite brittle: things will go awry if the user inputs more than 6 characters: remember to set one byte aside for the nul-terminator `\0`. As an absolute minimum, write `scanf("%6s", password);` and run your loop to the first `\0` rather than 7. See [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) for more details.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>= 1`, not `> 1`?

Comment: @Barmar: Yup. Amended. We'll publish jointly.

Comment: You could also simplify it to `if (u && d && s)`. And the weak test would be `if(!u || !d || !s)`

Comment: @Barmar: Indeed you could, but I'd only ever do that for `unsigned` types. A bit OCD I know.

Comment: Well, these variables probably should be unsigned. You can't have a negative number of characters of each type.

Answer (score 0):

```
int issymbol(int password)
```

Your variable `password` should be `char` type to check symbols instead of `int`.

Edit:

```
scanf("%s", password);
```

Always put space before `%s`, like

```
scanf(" %s", password)
```

This will terminate all previous `\n`.

Comment: Should i also put " %6s".

Comment: Nope: the password is the first thing the user types. The leading space is a crude, but occasionally effective, way of passing over the newline character that's sent to the input buffer when the user types return.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're checking more characters than you typed. If you type `SS7`, there are only 3 characters to check, but your `for` loop checks all `7` characters in `password`. The characters after `password[3]` will be uninitialized, and they might contain characters that meet the requirements.

Change the loop to:

```
for (i = 0; password[i]; i++) {
```

This will stop when it reaches the terminating null character in the string.